# How to instantiate Ext views for testing in jasmine

Tags: extjs, jasmine

I want to test Views in Ext4, but

```
Application.getView
```

returns constructor function, and I run out of ideas how to make it work.

```
describe("general", function() {
    it("should have fields enabled by default", function(){
        var view = Application.getView('BRM.view.business_rule.form_part.General'),
            viewInstance = new view(),
            items = viewInstance.items
        ;
        _.each(items, function(item){
            console.log(item);
            debugger;
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the create method:

```
var viewInstance = Application.getView('BRM.view.business_rule.form_part.General').create();
var items = viewInstance.items;
```

Alternatively you can also use  Ext.create:

```
Ext.create('BRM.view.business_rule.form_part.General')
```